# Finding malicious script on my webserver with grep

Tags: php, wordpress, malware-detection

Got a malicious script on my WordPress site, randomly appearing and disappearing
in my source code as

```
<script src="www.71wp.org/jquery.min.js></script>
```

I have custom designed footer.php file, I figured out that the script is getting echoed into the footer somehow, because if I delete  from my footer, that's the only script that I have there then the malicious script won't appear anymore.

I have been using this to find the source of the virus, and so far no success.
find . -name "*.php" -exec grep "base64" '{}' \; -print &> b64-detections.txt
find . -name "*.php" -exec grep "eval" '{}' \; -print &> eval-detections.txt

Anyone might have any ideas how I can locate this script?

Comment: Why is this question tagged javascript?

Comment: I will suggest you run a scan of all your wordpress files by installing this plugin Sucuri Security it will give you detailed report of malicious code in any file on your wordpress

Answer (score 1):

Hye

I also tried with :

```
eval()
base64_decode()
String.fromCharCode
```

I have a SSH access if needed

Which plugins do you used. The hack is coming only on the mobile version

Tks

Answer (score 1):

This is what exactly happening in your case

https://blog.sucuri.net/2015/05/fake-jquery-scripts-in-nulled-wordpress-pugins.html

You need to search this function all over your wordpress

```
function wp_func_jquery() {}
```

Code inside this function varies with different sites but the function name remains same in all site. It is commonly found in functions.php, footer.php or in any plugin file. It mostly comes through nulled or pirated plugins.